# Single Choice Lists and onClick events

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE list with 3 rows.  How do I place an onClick event that changes the value of an arbitrary variable, so that if Row 1 is clicked, say, the value of X = 1, and when Row 2 is clicked, the value of X = 2, etc.?

```
    public class List extends ListActivity {  
 @Override    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, GENRES));        
        final ListView listView = getListView();        
        listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);        
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);    
    }    

private static final String[] GENRES = new String[] {"Barre", "Buffumville","Hodges"};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its quite simple..rather than extending ListActivity extend it by Activity and just declare listview in your XML file as below:

```
<ListView 
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

initialize listview in your activity:

```
ListView listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

And after setting adapter as you did,set the item click listener of the listview as below in your code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), GENRES[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

By doing this you will get the desired value of that position of listview.
You will surely get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the onItemClickListener on the list view.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(
     new OnItemClickListener(
          @Override
          onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View cell, int position, long id) {
               // Code to change variables
          }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)` in your ListActivity, and the position variable lets you know which item was clicked.